# How to use a large external drive in WSL with reasonable performance

Tags: mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, io

I have a 250GB WSL 2 partition running Ubuntu (on Windows 10), inside which I do my development. I'm working with some files that are too big for this partition. I have attached an external 6TB USB drive and mounted it with drvfs.

> `drvfs on /mnt/d type 9p (rw,relatime,dirsync,aname=drvfs;path=d:;symlinkroot=/mnt/,mmap,access=client,msize=262144,trans=virtio)`

The performance reading and writing files is terrible. A task that should take less than a minute to run looks like it might take hours.

I understand this is a known issue: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4197

Are there any solutions or reasonable workarounds?

Comment: I am currently running a full install of Ubuntu on my external drive SSD. I bought a NVMe drive & USB/NVMe adapter. It will not run faster than SATA SSD on USB3, but expect in future to have faster USB-C ports, so bought NVMe, It is almost as fast as internal SSD. Are you using NTFS or ext4. With Linux use Linux formats.